# iptables - where are they generated or loaded from in the boot sequence?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, centos7

I can't work out how iptables are loaded at boot on a centos7.7 system.
Iptables-services is not installed.  I am aware of the move to firewalld, but I want to *know* how the kernel is setting up it's iptables rules.

The significant thing for me is that the FORWARD chain has a reject from anywhere rule:

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

which drops all packets from not specifically mentioned in earlier rules:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.100.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.100.0/24     anywhere
...
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.101.0/24
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.101.0/24     anywhere
```

It's easy enough to fix - I simply run this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -j ACCEPT -s 192.168.0.0/16
```

But I'd like to know how these rules are loaded - and if possible, how to modify that process.

Recursively grepping in /etc/systemd and in /usr/lib/systemd for iptables returns nothing.  I've come to the conclusion that the kernel is deciding on a default ruleset at boot, based on the network config. (I've disabled NetworkManager). Nothing in the rc.d hierarchy.  Is the kernel saying "aha I have these interfaces, I'll allow forwarding between them" ?

I've experimented, rebooted quite a few times (actually, a VM might be a better experimentation platform, it occurs to me), read the man page for iptables, and various internet resources, which mostly say how to load the rules you want, usually using iptables-services.  I'm fine with making the rules which I want, but am mystified as to where the default rules are created.

There's nothing referring to iptables in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts, either.

To clarify:
Firewalld is not installed.  The service file is present, but is masked in /etc/systemd/system

Comment: CentOS 7 is probably using firewalld

Comment: Thanks, but the third sentence mentions that.  To be clearer, firewalld is not installed, and the service is masked.

Comment: OK, then the other things that are likely to set up rules during startup are things like Docker and libvrit (or other Virtual Machine engines) all of which will insert their own rules into the forward tables to be allow containers/vms to be able to reach the outside world.

Comment: Yeah, though of that - docker is not running .

Comment: I removed docker for that reason - and you've got it , I think - it's a KVM server.  Thanks - I'll go and look at that.